# Converse of corollary about nilpotent operators, how to prove

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to prove the converse of this corollary.

Suppose N is a nilpotent mapping of a finite dimensional vector space V with  index of nilpotency m. Let $n_i=$Nullity$N^i$ for $i=0,..,m$. The quantities $d_i=n_i-n_{i-1}$ ($i=1,..,m$) form a monotone decreasing sequence.

What I've been trying is this.

We choose $d_i$ to be number of elements in i-th column of tableau. Is this enough? Should I prove that m is index of nilpotency and how?

Comment: It would help if you could explicitly write down the statement you are trying to prove here. Are you given monotonically decreasing $d_i, i=1,2,\ldots,m$'s and you are trying to prove that there *exists* a nilpotent operator $N$  with nilpotency $m$ such that, if $n_i=\text{Nullity}(N^i)$ then $n_i-n_{i-1}$ are precisely the $d_i$'s you chose before?

Comment: (If that is what you are trying to do, try to think of the matrix $N$ which is already in the Jordan canonical form.)

Comment: Yes, if I have $d_i$-s, how can I construct N?

Comment: I am not supposed to use Jordan canonical form, is it possible to prove it with tableau?

Comment: @Novak You don't need the fact that every matrix has a Jordan form, you just need to use Jordan blocks to construct suitable examples.

Comment: No need even to call them Jordan blocks ;). Say $J_k=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&1\\0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\end{pmatrix}$... You have $\text{Nullity}(J_k^i)=i$ etc. - you just need to line up the appropriately-sized blocks $J_{k_1}, J_{k_2}$ etc. on the diagonal - make a block-diagonal matrix $N$ and then fit the sizes $k_1, k_2$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment on your question suggests, it is helpful to think in terms of Jordan normal form. I recommend the following:

- Argue that for each $i$, $d_i = n_i - n_{i-1}$ is the number of Jordan blocks (associated with $0$) in the Jordan form of $N$ that have size at least $i$
- Using this information, deduce the Jordan form of $N$ in terms of the decreasing sequence $d_1,d_2,\dots$.

Alternatively, you could use [Weyr canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyr_canonical_form), which in a sense builds a matrix directly from the resulting tableaux.

For more information, note that the sequence of $d_i$ is sometimes referred to as the Weyr characrteristic. This sequence is discussed in detail [here for instance](https://works.swarthmore.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1027&context=fac-math-stat).